# Change wordpress current_time function to different timezone

Tags: plugins, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, timestamp, timezones

I'm using plugin to set the earliest possible date for order delivery in woocommerce.

> Piece of code below:

```
$current_time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
        if( $prdd_minimum_delivery_time != '' && $prdd_minimum_delivery_time != 0 ) {
            $advance_seconds = $prdd_minimum_delivery_time *60 *60;
            $cut_off_timestamp = $current_time + $advance_seconds;
            $cut_off_date = date( "d-m-Y", $cut_off_timestamp );
            $min_date = date( "j-n-Y", strtotime( $cut_off_date ) );
        } else {
            $min_date = date( "j-n-Y", $current_time );
```

> Then piece of code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    var formats = ["d.m.y", "d-m-yy","MM d, yy"];
                    var min_date = jQuery( "#prdd_lite_hidden_minimum_delivery_time" ).val();
                    var split_date = min_date.split( "-" );
                    var min_date_to_set = new Date ( split_date[1] + "/" + split_date[0] + "/" + split_date[2] );
                    var fourWorkingDays = new Date();
                    var adjustments = [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]; // Offsets by day of the week, sunday is first day here
```

I'm adding 1-2 day offset but my goal is to set it to rule "order to 3p.m. to get tommorrow" How can I modify that?

Answer (score 1):

`current_time()` supports GMT as the second parameter.

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/current_time

If no second parameter is passed it should return the timezone set for your site.